# Is the Hubble parameter a frequency and if it is what is it a frequency for?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, frequency

Logic and a bit of math lead to the conclusion that the [Hubble parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble_parameter) is a frequency since its unit is

$$ \frac {\mathrm{km}}{\mathrm{Mpc} \cdot s} $$

where *[km](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilometre)* and  *[Mpc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilometre)* are both units of [length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length), so if you transform them accordingly you can cancel them out to

$$ \text s^{-1} = \mathrm{Hz}. $$

But what is this frequency for?

Answer (score 4):

The large-scale structure of the universe is one on which lengths scale in proportion to a time-dependent function called the scale factor, denotes $a(t)$. If over some period $a$ doubles, that just means the large-scale structure of the universe doubles its length scales. The Hubble parameter $H=\frac{\dot{a}}{a}$ is in general time-dependent. In fact, the only way for it to be constant is for $a$ to vary exponentially over time (viz. $a\propto e^{Ht}$, in which cases $1/H$ is the time $a$ takes to multiply by $e$). In most of the universe's history, we have had $a\propto t^p$ with $p$ approximately constant for long time periods and $t$ the time since the Big Bang. Then $H=\frac{p}{t}$ is inversely proportional to the age of the universe.

Answer (score -4):

The way Hubble constant is presented is quite misleading.The reason for that was "to fit"  Hubble data misinterpreted via Doppler shift with R dot over R term of Friedman solution of Einstein equations.  The simplest way to see what Hubble constant is, one should to calculate it in  METERS . Take MKS units, velocity m/s, distance m . Then you will see that H has dimension 1/m.
H squared has dimension 1/m squared which is the (negative) Gaussian curvature of Lobachevskian Universe understood as Poincare ball model of Lobachevskian geometry. As a reference see " Expansion of Universe -Mistake of Edwin Hubble ..." Acta Physica Polonica B ,vol 39,nr.8, 2008.

Comment: In MKS units, the Hubble constant has units [m/s per meter], i.e. $\mathrm{s}^{-1}$, as it should. I don't know how you arrive at $\mathrm{m}^{-1}$.

Comment: You somehow forgot  that c=1 is an universal constant so it  is equally valid to measure ( please do not be shocked) time in METRES which I personally prefer , since distance is well mathematically defined while time is something which everybody uses but nobody can define. As an exercise try to calculate what will be one second in meters. Regards.

Comment: Well, then it's not really MKS units anymore. Also, please stop advertising your own work. This is not the place, especially considering to non-mainstream nature of your ideas.

Comment: Physics is done by those individuals who are not in the "mainstream". Being in the  "mainstream" you can eat only  already digested food. Regards

Comment: That's a valid point of view, although I disagree in both statements. But this is a site for mainstream physics.

Comment: For two thousands years "mainstream physics" told us that the Sun orbits the Earth and those who disagreed like Italian Giordano Bruno were burn to death as heretics. Then came Copernicus and  we know, thanks to him, that whose believe in mainstream for 2000 years were wrong.  Today people , like myself, who are not convinced what is written in some textbooks are denied the  right to explain their view like this site did for me. How you can vote on chicken soup if you never tried one?

Comment: There _are_ places where you can express that point of view. [viXra.org](http://vixra.org), for instance. You have to respect that some places, people are not interested in your hypotheses.