Dimensionality of the Hubble constant
According to Wikipedia,

The Hubble constant is most frequently quoted in (km/s)/Mpc

Since both km and Mpc are lengths, dimensionality of the Hubble constant comes out 1/time, i.e. frequency. As such, it is then about $2.1978\times10^{-18}$ Hz. This is the frequency of what?

Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/328314/2451

The reciprocal of the Hubble constant — a time —  is easier to grasp. Try computing it in years.
